# Filter products by category on Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, filter, field, product

I want to filter all products of the category shirts to add a custom field on all shirts. Because I don't want to add that custom field in the rest products. So I want the custom field visible on product page, cart and checkout.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the following filter to filter the item name on the cart and checkout: `woocommerce_after_cart_item_name`

To add something to your product page you can choose from a variety of actions to hook into. Here is a [visual overview](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/).

In the following example I've chosen to add something before the add to cart form on the product page.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'product_page_show_field_based_on_category', 10 ); 
function product_page_show_field_based_on_category() {
    global $product;
    if ( has_cat( $product->get_category_ids() ) ) {
        echo "<p>Has category Shirt</p>";
    } 
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'checkout_and_cart_show_field_based_on_category', 10, 3 );
function checkout_and_cart_show_field_based_on_category( $product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if ( has_cat( $cart_item['data']->get_category_ids() ) ) {
        $product_name .= "<p>Has category Shirt</p>";
    }
    return $product_name;
}

function has_cat( $cat_ids ) {
    $cat_id = 1; //set your shirt category id here
    return in_array( $cat_id, $cat_ids) ? true : false;
}
```

Both filter and action make use of a small helper function to check for the category id.

Comment: I can't vote, I'm new. Thank you for your answer. Then I can use: if($product->get_categories("shirt")){}

Comment: You won't have to. The `has_cat()` function will check for you if your product has a category of 'Shirt'. Simply set the shirt category id in the first line of the `has_cat()` function. [Click here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/find-product-category-ids/) for some help on finding your category id.

If this answer works for you, you can [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thank you in advance!